# How to get Box-Shadow to render above another element?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}

#superheader {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#superheader p {
  font-family: Sansation;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0.0
}

#superheader table {
  border: none;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

#header {
  height: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0em 0em 1em 0.2em grey;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menuelement {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;

}

.menuelement:hover {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  color: lightgray;
}

#header>a {
  line-height: 2.5;
}

#page {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0em 0.6em 0.5em grey;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  height: 6000px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="superheader">
    <div style="margin: auto; width: 630px;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="images/memoji.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="Icon" </td> <td>
            <p>Title</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="page1.html">
    <div class="menuelement">page1</div>
  </a>
  <a href="index.html">
    <div class="menuelement">Startseite</div>
  </a>
  <a href="page2.html">
    <div class="menuelement">page2</div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <h1>First Headline</h1>
  <h2>Second Headline</h2>
  <p>Some text.</p>
</div>
```

The box-shadow of the header-div is not rendering above the page-div but is hidden below it. 
How can I get the box-shadow to render on the page-div, so that it is visible there?
Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: Add some z-index on the element, like   #header { z-index: 1; }

Comment: shadows are passé

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header `box-shadow` is hidden by the `page` selector because the `header` selector stack order is lower than the `page` selector.

So it is needed to modify the stack order of `header` selector to be higher than `page` selector.

That can be done using `z-index`. And add `z-index: 1` (any value higher than 0 because default z-index: auto (= 0)) to `#header` class and you will see the `box-shadow`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}

#superheader {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#superheader p {
  font-family: Sansation;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0.0
}

#superheader table {
  border: none;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

#header {
  height: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0em 0em 1em 0.2em grey;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
  z-index: 5;
}

.menuelement {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;

}

.menuelement:hover {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  color: lightgray;
}

#header>a {
  line-height: 2.5;
}

#page {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0em 0.6em 0.5em grey;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  height: 6000px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="superheader">
    <div style="margin: auto; width: 630px;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="images/memoji.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="Icon" </td> <td>
            <p>Title</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="page1.html">
    <div class="menuelement">page1</div>
  </a>
  <a href="index.html">
    <div class="menuelement">Startseite</div>
  </a>
  <a href="page2.html">
    <div class="menuelement">page2</div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <h1>First Headline</h1>
  <h2>Second Headline</h2>
  <p>Some text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the z-index of the header.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}

#superheader {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#superheader p {
  font-family: Sansation;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0.0
}

#superheader table {
  border: none;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

#header {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0em 0em 1em 0.2em grey;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menuelement {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;

}

.menuelement:hover {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  color: lightgray;
}

#header>a {
  line-height: 2.5;
}

#page {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0em 0.6em 0.5em grey;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  height: 6000px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="superheader">
    <div style="margin: auto; width: 630px;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="images/memoji.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="Icon" </td> <td>
            <p>Title</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="page1.html">
    <div class="menuelement">page1</div>
  </a>
  <a href="index.html">
    <div class="menuelement">Startseite</div>
  </a>
  <a href="page2.html">
    <div class="menuelement">page2</div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <h1>First Headline</h1>
  <h2>Second Headline</h2>
  <p>Some text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}

#superheader {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#superheader p {
  font-family: Sansation;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0.0
}

#superheader table {
  border: none;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

#header {
  height: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0em 0em 1em 0.2em grey;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menuelement {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;

}

.menuelement:hover {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  color: lightgray;
}

#header>a {
  line-height: 2.5;
}

#page {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0em 0.6em 0.5em grey;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  height: 6000px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="superheader">
    <div style="margin: auto; width: 630px;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="images/memoji.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="Icon" </td> <td>
            <p>Title</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="page1.html">
    <div class="menuelement">page1</div>
  </a>
  <a href="index.html">
    <div class="menuelement">Startseite</div>
  </a>
  <a href="page2.html">
    <div class="menuelement">page2</div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <h1>First Headline</h1>
  <h2>Second Headline</h2>
  <p>Some text.</p>
</div>
```

You can use a css rule called `z-index`. CSS-Tricks writes:

> The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically closer to you. z-index only affects elements that have a position value other than static (the default).
> So elements with a higher `z-index` value appear closer to the viewer.